# Sending e-mail in Laravel with custom HTML

Tags: php, email, laravel

I need to send e-mails but I already have the HTML generated, I don't want to use laravel blade because I need to apply a CSS Inliner to the HTML, so this is how i generate the html:

```
getRenderedView($viewData) {
    //code
    $html =  View::make('email.notification', $viewData)->render();
    $this->cssInliner->setCSS($this->getCssForNotificationEmail());
    $this->cssInliner->setHTML($html);
    return $this->cssInliner->convert();
}
```

So, to send the mail with Laravel you usually do something like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

But I don't want to pass a view, I already have the html, how can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I'm right in what you want to achieve, to get round this I created a view called echo.php and inside that just echo $html.

Assign your html to something like $data['html'].

Then below pass your $data['html'] to the echo view.

`Mail::send('emails.echo', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});`

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: This method can also be used to good effect with templates too when using separated header footer etc.

Answer (score 6):

I want to share a tip which might help sending emails without "blade".

Laravel Mail function is actually a wrapper for Swift. 
Just assign empty arrays to $template and $data, I mean the first 2 parameters of the function, then do the rest inside callback.

```
Mail::send([], [], function($message) use($to, $title, $email_body)
{
    $message->setBody($email_body)->to($to)->subject($title);
});
```

Comment: Got this when tried to use your solution mate

Call to undefined method Swift_Message::to()

Answer (score 1):

The body is not accessible from the closure.

You can create the swift message by hand:

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setFrom($messageToParse->template['fromEmail']);
    $message->setTo($messageToParse->to['email']);
    $message->setBody($messageToParse->body);
    $message->addPart($messageToParse->body, 'html contents');
    $message->setSubject('subject');
```

But then you to need to create the transport:

```
    $mailer = self::setMailer( [your transport] );
    $response =  $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Can you discuss what "your transport" looks like?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
Mail::to("xyz.gmail.com")->send(new contactMailAdmin($userData));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array( 'email' => 'sample@domail.com', 'first_name' => 'Laravel', 
        'from' => 'sample@domail.comt', 'from_name' => 'learming' );

Mail::send( 'email.welcome', $data, function( $message ) use ($data)
{
 $message->to( $data['email'] )->from( $data['from'], 
 $data['first_name'] )->subject( 'Welcome!' );
 });
```