# Translate queued mails (localization)

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking for a working solution, to **translate queued emails** in [laravel-5](/questions/tagged/laravel-5). 
Unfortunately, all emails use the **default locale** (defined under `app.locale`).

Let's assume, we have two emails in the *pipeline*, one for an English `en` user and another for an Japanese `jp` user.

What data should I pass to the `Mail` facade to **translate** (localize) the **queued emails**?

```
  // User model
  $user = User:find(1)->first();

  Mailer::queue($email, 'Party at Batman\'s cave (Batcave)', 'emails.party-invitation', [

    ...

    'locale' => $user->getLocale(), // value: "jp", but does not work
    'lang' => $user->getLocale(), // value: "jp", but does not work
    'language' => $user->getLocale(), // value: "jp", but does not work
  ]);
```

Comment: I think you should add Laravel to the question

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The question is tagged with [tag:laravel], or should I consider to contact the developers of the framework?

Comment: I thought it may attract some attention or help with google searches. I could however, be sorely mistaken and it may not help at all ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been struggling to get this done in a more efficient way. Currently I have it set up like this. Hopefully this helps someone in the future with this issue:

```php
// Fetch the locale of the receiver.
$user = Auth::user();
$locale = $user->locale;
Mail::queue('emails.welcome.template', ['user' => $user, 'locale' => $locale], function($mail) use ($user, $locale) {
     $mail->to($user->email);
     $mail->subject(
          trans(
               'mails.subject_welcome',
               [], null, $locale
          )
     );
});
```

And use the following in your template:

```
{{ trans('mails.welcome', ['name' => ucfirst($user['first_name'])], null, $locale) }}
```

**Note**: do not forget to restart your queue

Comment: Is you just have a few emails this is ok. Otherwise the solution of pinguinjkeke is better..

Comment: Woww, your code works bro thank you. But i lost 2 hours trying to make it works till i restarted queue. No change will take effect if you do not restart queue. i didn't know that.

Comment: You've just made my day. thank you so much for sharing that. it's really useful.

Comment: 8 Years later, your little note at the end saved me after days of debugging! Thanks! It should probably common knowledge but I never worked with queues and took this project over from another developer and we were having massive problem on prod now because of that issue. Finally it is fixed!

Answer (score 3):

If your emails inherits the built-in `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` class you can build your own Mailable class that will take care of translations.

Create your own `SendQueuedMailable` class that inherits from `Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable`.
Class constructor will take current app.location from config and remember it in a property (because laravel queues serializes it).
In queue worker it will take the property back from config and set the setting to the current environment.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as MailerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable as MailableContract;
use Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable as IlluminateSendQueuedMailable;

class SendQueuedMailable extends IlluminateSendQueuedMailable
{
    protected $locale;

    public function __construct(MailableContract $mailable)
    {
        parent::__construct($mailable);

        $this->locale = config('app.locale');
    }

    public function handle(MailerContract $mailer)
    {
        config(['app.locale' => $this->locale]);
        app('translator')->setLocale($this->locale);

        parent::handle($mailer);
    }
}
```

Then, create your own `Mail` class that inherits from `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory as Queue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable as IlluminateMailable;

class Mailable extends IlluminateMailable
{
    public function queue(Queue $queue)
    {
        $connection = property_exists($this, 'connection') ? $this->connection : null;

        $queueName = property_exists($this, 'queue') ? $this->queue : null;

        return $queue->connection($connection)->pushOn(
            $queueName ?: null, new SendQueuedMailable($this)
        );
    }
}
```

And, voila, all your queued mailables inherited from `App\Mailable` class automatically will take care of current locale.

Comment: I think when u use sync as queue driver (not recommended in production) then you must set the locale back in the SendQueuedMailable __destruct(). Otherwise the app runs in the false language after sending the email.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.6 is a locale function added to Mailable:
$infoMail->locale('jp');
Mail::queue($infoMail);

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.7.7 introduced the `HasLocalePreference` interface to solve this issue.

```
class User extends Model implements HasLocalePreference
{
    public function preferredLocale() { return $this->locale; }
}
```

Now if you use `Mail::to()` function, Laravel will send with the correct locale.

Also introduced was the `Mail` chainable `locale()` function.

```
Mail::to($address)->locale($locale)->send(new Email());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me. In my example, I am processing the booking on a queue, using a dedicated `Job` class.

When you dispatch a job on a queue, pass the locale, you want your email in. For example:

```
ProcessBooking::dispatch($booking, \App::getLocale());
```

Then, in your job class (`ProcessBooking` in my example) store the locale in a property:

```
protected $booking;
protected $locale;

public function __construct(Booking $booking, $locale)
{
    $this->booking = $booking;
    $this->locale = $locale;
}
```

And in your `handle` method temporarily switch locales:

```
public function handle()
{
    // store the locale the queue is currently running in
    $previousLocale = \App::getLocale();

    // change the locale to the one you need for job to run in
    \App::setLocale($this->locale);

    // Do the stuff you need, e.g. send an email
    Mail::to($this->booking->customer->email)->send(new NewBooking($this->booking));

    // go back to the original locale
    \App::setLocale($previousLocale);
}
```

Why do we need to do this?

Queued emails get the default locale since queue workers are separate Laravel apps. If you ever ran into a problem, when you cleared your cache, but queued 'stuff' (e.g. emails) still showed the old content, it's because of that. Here's an explanation from [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker):

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

Comment: The solution of pinguinjkeke is better. Here you have to do it for every mail.

Answer (score 0):

using `preferredLocale()` is the "*official*" way to go.

you can implement HasLocalePreference and add method preferredLocale() to the notifiable model (as @Peter-M suggested):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\HasLocalePreference;

class User extends Model implements HasLocalePreference
{
    /**
     * Get the user's preferred locale.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function preferredLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }
}
```

and then you just send the notification to that model and locale will be automatically applied to your email template

```
$user->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

This also works with queued mail notifications.

read more here:
https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-change-language-for-laravel-email-notifications

Answer (score -1):

I'm faced with the same problem

Without extending the queue class the quickest / dirtiest solution would be to create an email template for each locale.

Then when you create the queue, select the local template i.e.

```
Mail::queue('emails.'.App::getLocale().'notification', function($message) 
{
    $message->to($emails)->subject('hello');
});
```

If the local is set to IT (italian) This will load the view emails/itnotification.blade.php

As I said... Dirty!

Since this method is actually horrible I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24905800/283434)
And its working for me, you actually send the entire translated html version of the email in a variable to the queue and have a blank blade file that echos out the variable when the queue runs.

Comment: This is absolutely not efficient. What if I have a website in 40 languages? I would have a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: @turncoat agreed, it's not efficient however it is a solution and I did say it was "dirty".