# How to cache email html on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Im working with laravel framework and i need to save html to cache file, .html or etc. file to show on the browser than the link is clicked in the newsletter email. (link: View email in browser).

in the integration.blade.php are included `@include('emails/header')` and `@include('emails/footer')`

here is the mail send code:

```
Mail::send('emails/integration', array('type' => ucfirst($type)), function($message) use ($type)
    {
    $message->to( Auth::user()->email, Auth::user()->fullname)->subject('Successful name and '.ucfirst($type).' store integration!');
    });
```

After this i need cache html.

View email in browser link to be like address.com/email/?html=gbfvisbiudoanlfdlsakdnlsakndlasn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the main principle used in [Sending e-mail in Laravel with custom HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905202/sending-e-mail-in-laravel-with-custom-html) but after making the view you can cache it:

```
$minutes = ...
$viewData = [
    'type' => ucfirst($type)
];
$html = Cache::remember('email/integration', $minutes, function()
{
    return View::make('email/integration', $viewData)->render();
});

Mail::send('emails.echo', ['html' => $html], function($message) use ($type)
{
    $message->to(Auth::user()->email, Auth::user()->fullname)->subject('Successful name and '.ucfirst($type).' store integration!');
});
```

Code is untested but I'm sure you get the principle.